# What are some well known personalities who belonged to multiple sects simultaneously?

Tags: sects, appayya-dikshitar

Appayya Dikshitar was a sixteenth century Shaivite who was simultaneously initiated in both the Smarta tradition (which advocates Advaita Vedanta) and the Shrouta Saiva Siddhanta tradition (which advocates Shivadvaita Vedanta).

Are there any well known personalities who, like Appayya Dikshitar, belonged to multiple sects simultaneously?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Āchārya Abhinavgupta - was even initiated into Advait Vedanta.

Comment: Did he follow Kashmiri Shaivism and Smartha dharma simultaneously? @Rohit.